How do I stop the CPU from throttling?
A little background first: (Maybe a little longwinded)
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS [5.15.0-101-generic|libc 2.35]
Gigabyte B550M K using optimum BIOS settings, 32GB, Noctua DH-15 cooler (2 fans), basic video card, AMD 5950x
Doing community computing using Boinc software with 3 projects (World community Grid, Rosetta@home, and Denis@home)
All cores are being used 24/7 which is normal.
cat /proc/cpuinfo | greb "MHz" shows the frequency varying amongst 34nn, 25nn, and 5nn
top shows %CPU varying from 95% to 104%
temps are at 46 C. It should be cooking at about 75 C.
As a reference I also have an ASUS B550M K, 32GB, Noctua DH-15s cooler (1 fan), basic video card, AMD 3900x doing the same work.
The CPU is always steady at 4000 MHz (BIOS tweak)
top varies from 99.6% and 100.3%
temps are 73.8 C
I found a setting on the ASUS (CPU Core Ratio) which allowed me to change the MHz from 3800 to 4000 and the AI tweak lowered the voltage a bit to reduce the heat. No throttling here.
I found no such setting on the Gigabyte advanced mode although the docs show there is. I disabled the AMD Cool & Quiet. It did nothing. Core Performance Boost seemed to describe my situation. Turning it off in two places did nothing. Maybe the 5950x cannot be under/over clocked. The docs says it can.
I read that Windows running on the board has vendor supplied software which can set and change settings. So now I turn to software using Linux.
I install cpupower-gui and run it. The Governor is set to onDemand. I set it to performance on all CPUs and set the minimum to the same as maximum (3400). All the stats are the same as described above. This does not survive a boot but I could live with that.
The consequence of this throttling is that a workunit which takes one hour on the 3900x takes about two hours on the 5950x. It's not what I expected by getting a more powerful CPU.
I could install a Windows 10 and see if there are any options I could set in the BIOS which are not presented on boot.

maybe try configuring boinc preferences. Im assuming this set up is doing 100 calculations, and youre not also trying to use the PC for normal desktop use. You might look at what boinc is doing in terms of performance. https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Client_configuration
the iostat & vmstat utilities may help you debug performance. For example, if you see a large number of (CS) context switches, and low free memory, perhaps disk utilization is driving a bottleneck.
Boinc also keeps detailed performance logs you might want to look at.

You are correct. The machine is not used for anything else. The Boinc version is the same on all three machines and is using defaults. Most of the memory is free as seen in "top".
I had to lookup what is CS. Everything I've read tells me it becomes a problem when you are in the thousands or tens of thousands per second. I saw 21 yesterday and 4 today.

And I forgot to mention that most of the disk is free.

This is now solved. I replaced the Gigabyte B550MK motherboard with another ASUS B550MK. Now the times are about like my other machines at about 1.6 hrs. They used to take about 3.5 hrs with the Gigabyte B550MK.
I did the same little tuning as on the others and now the thing runs steady at 3500 Mhz with a temp of about 67 Celsius. I'm in a heat wave now at 83F or 28C. And I didn't even have to use the second fan on the Noctua NH-D15.
I am pleased. Not much to be said of Gigabyte. I reached out to their support and they are looking in to it since April.
